How to Prevent Inserting New Exercise Types When Creating a Workout in Xamarin Android App?
I'm developing a Xamarin Android app for managing workouts, where users can create workouts consisting of exercises categorized by exercise types. Each exercise type is associated with specific attributes such as name, description, and targeted muscle group.
I've encountered an issue when creating a workout in my app. Upon attempting to save the workout data to the database, I receive the following error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ExerciseTypes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

It seems that Entity Framework Core is trying to insert new records into the 'ExerciseTypes' table, even though I only want to associate existing exercise types with the workout.
Here's a summary of my code logic:
I have a Workout class representing a workout, which contains a collection of ExerciseTypeGroup objects.
Each ExerciseTypeGroup object has an associated ExerciseType and a collection of Exercise objects.
When creating a workout, I retrieve existing exercise types from the database and associate them with the workout.
I'm not intending to insert new exercise types when creating a workout; I only want to use existing ones.
I suspect that there might be a flaw in my code logic or database configuration that's causing Entity Framework Core to attempt to insert new exercise types.
 private async void CompleteWorkout()
 {
     Workout workout = new Workout();
     workout.ExerciseTypeGroups = new List<ExerciseTypeGroup>(ExerciseTypeGroups);
     string userIdString = Preferences.Get("UserID", defaultValue: null);
     if (int.TryParse(userIdString, out int userId))
     {
         
         workout.CreatorId = userId;
         foreach (var item in workout.ExerciseTypeGroups)
         {
             ExerciseType exerciseTypefromDb = await ExerciseTypeManager.ReadAsync(item.ExerciseType.ExerciseTypeId); //smenq exercise type s tozi ot bazata danni
             item.ExerciseType = exerciseTypefromDb;
         }
         await WorkoutManager.CreateAsync(workout);
        
     }
 }

public async Task CreateAsync(Workout item)
{
    try
    {
        dbContext.Workouts.Add(item);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

   public class ExerciseTypeGroup
   {
       [Key]
       public int ExerciseTypeGroupId { get; set; }
       public ExerciseType ExerciseType { get; set; }
       public List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

       public ExerciseTypeGroup()
       {
           Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
       }
   }


  public class ExerciseType
  {
      [Key]
      public int ExerciseTypeId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string? Description { get; set; }
      public BodyParts? TargetedMuscle { get; set; }

      public Equipment? Equipment { get; set; }


      public ExerciseType()
      {

      }
      public ExerciseType(string name, string description, BodyParts targetedmuscle, Equipment equipment)
      {
          Name = name;
          Description = description;
          TargetedMuscle = targetedmuscle;
          Equipment = equipment;
      }
  }

public class Workout
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }

    public List<ExerciseTypeGroup> ExerciseTypeGroups { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public User? Creator { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public Workout()
    {
        ExerciseTypeGroups = new List<ExerciseTypeGroup>();
    }
    public Workout(User user)
    {
        Status = Status.Waiting;
        Creator = user;
        ExerciseTypeGroups = new List<ExerciseTypeGroup>();
    }

Could someone please advise on the best approach to prevent Entity Framework Core from attempting to insert new exercise types when creating a workout? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
